# How can I customize the PagedList.Core.MVC to the way I need to shape it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc, pagedlist

I currently have a pager in an MVC view, it's dynamic and does everything for me in the background:

```
 <pager class="pager" list="@Model" options="@PagedListRenderOptions.TwitterBootstrapPager" asp-action="NieuwsOverzicht" asp-controller="Nieuws" />
```

I was able to customize its colour:

CSS

```
.pager > li > a {
    color: black !Important;
    border-color: white !Important;
    padding: 5px !Important;
}
```

But I don't know how I can customize the buttons individually. This is what it currently looks like. I'm using the PagedList.Core.MVC package v1.0.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO5Ht.png

ViewImports cshtml

```
@using Groep1D
@using PagedList.Core.Mvc
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, PagedList.Core.Mvc
```

Services in startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

This is the CSS I want to implement for the pager. I need two arrows and the page numbers separately styled.

```
  .pager > li > a.right-arrow {
        margin-left: 340px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #9ecaed;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 7px;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .pager > li > a.left-arrow {
        margin-right: 340px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #9ecaed;
        font-size: 15px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        padding: 7px;
        line-height: 1;
    }


.number {
    color: black !Important;
    border-color: white !Important;
    padding: 5px !Important;
}
```

```html
<div class="pager">
<ul class="pager">
<li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="/Nieuws/NieuwsOverzicht?page=1" rel="prev">Previous</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/Nieuws/NieuwsOverzicht?page=1">1</a>
</li>
<li class="active"><a>2</a>
</li>
<li class="disabled PagedList-skipToNext"><a rel="next">Next</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to style them? - e.g. for the first 'button' - `.pager > li > a:first { ...`

Comment: And show the html that is being generated by the plugin

Comment: I have added it I want to make arrows instead of words. I have added the CSS I used for a normal pager

Comment: I'm not able to change the CSS classes of the buttons somehow individually

Comment: Why does nobody want to help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to consult with the developer and/or any provided documentation (which doesn't appear to be much). A tag helper (which is what you're using here) merely programmatically constructs HTML to be rendered to the page. As such, what HTML is rendered is completely up to the tag helper and can only be modified in as much as the developer provides customization options. You'd need to determine what level of customization is actually available, and see if those can meet your needs.

Based on the code I'm seeing here, that's not much. It seems you simply get an enum of possible pagers and what you get is what you get with each one. As a result, my best advice is to simply create your own tag helper. It's actually very straight forward. A simplistic example would be something like:

```
public class PaginationTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    // Your paged items list auto-filled via a `page-list` attribute
    public IPagedList PageList { get; set; }

    // Injects the ViewContext (you'll need this access `Request`, build a `UrlHelper`, etc.)
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (PagedList.PageCount > 1)
        {
            // Replace the tag helper tag with the main wrapper element
            // In the case of a Bootstrap pager, that's `nav`
            output.TagName = "nav";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("aria-label", "page navigation");
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(BuildPager());
        }
        else
        {
            // If only one page, don't show the pager
            output.SupressOutput();
        }
    }

    public string BuildPager()
    {
        // craft the HTML you want and return as a string
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `IPagedList` is the interface all the actual `PagedList` types implement. It will give you access enough to properties you'll need like `PageNumber`, `PageCount`, `FirstItemOnPage`, `LastItemOnPage`, `TotalItemCount`, etc. to build your pager HTML
- To build the URL for each page link, you'll need to modify the current page URL query string to change the page number. Here's a simple method for that:

  ```
  private string GetUrlForPage(int page)
  {
      var uri = new Uri(ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl());
      var baseUri = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
      var query = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);
      var items = query.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (col, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(col.Key, value)).ToList();
      items.RemoveAll(x => x.Key == "page");

      var qb = new QueryBuilder(items);

      if (page > 1)
          qb.Add("page", page.ToString());

      return baseUri + qb.ToQueryString();
  }
  ```
- By default, a tag helper will replace an element named like the class (sans `TagHelper`. In this case, that would be `<pagination>`, based on the class name of `PaginationTagHelper`. If you want something different, you can either change the class name accordingly or utilize the `HtmlTargetElement` attribute (i.e. `[HtmlTargetElement("page")]`) on your class.
- You can also use the `HtmlTargetElement` attribute to control the tag structure (i.e. start and end tags, self-closing or both). If you set it to something like `TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing`, then you can use either `<page></page>` or just `<page />`. In the `Process` method, I've already added code to set the tag mode back to `TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag`, since `nav` needs an end tag.
- By default, public properties on the tag helper (e.g. `PageList` here) are available as attributes, translated from camelcase to lower-dash syntax. For example `PageList` becomes `page-list`. If you want something different, you can either change the property name or utilize the `HtmlAttributeName` attribute on the property (i.e. `[HtmlAttributeName("myattribute")]`).